# About some integer value functions

Tags: real-analysis, logic

I have the following logical case:
$$ \forall n \geq 1, \exists m \geq n, \exists j \geq n, \exists a,b,c,d,e,z,r,t,p \in \mathbb{N}: f(m,j,a,b,c,d,e,z,r,t,p)=0$$
where $$f(m,j,a,b,c,d,e,z,r,t,p)=u²(m,a,b,c)+v²(j,d,e,z)+w²(m,j,r,t,p)$$
where $u,v,w$ are polynomial functions and have integer values. I am not able to prove it. Then I negate it to get a case of the form:
$$ \exists n \geq 1, \forall m \geq n, \forall j \geq n, \forall a, b, c,d,e,z,r,t,p \in \mathbb{N}: f(m,j,a,b,c,d,e,z,r,t,p)>0.............................(B)$$

I want to show that this case if false. Then I proceed as follow: I find $m$ and $j$ *depending* on $n$ and some *fixed* $ a, b, c,d,e,z,r,t,p$ such that $$ f(m(n),j(n),a,b,c,d,e,z,r,t,p)≤0$$ for all $n$.
Hence, this disproof case $(B)$. However, this approach is very long and time-consuming.

Then my question is it is possible to use one of the polynomials $u,v,w$ instead.

Comment: If you can find a $u>0$ then it would prove the claim false too. It would be simpler because $u$ depends on $m(n)$ and not $j(n)$.

Comment: A typo, finding an f>0 would not disprove $(B)$, it would disprove your first claim. $(B)$ is precisely the case where there is an $f(\dots)>0$.

Comment: @user400188: So, there is no error in my approach for this proof.

Comment: Upon rereading this, I think that showing $f(m(n),j(n),\dots)$ for all n would not solve the question. You need to find a counter example to $(B)$ in order to show that the statement at the top of the page is true, if indeed it is.

Comment: @user400188: But this is exactly what I wrote to find a counterexample.

Comment: Finding an $f(m(n),j(n),\dots)>0$ for all $n$ is not a counterexample of $(B)$.

Comment: @user400188: Then how one can find such counterexample.

Comment: You could find an $f(m(n),j(n),\dots)\leq 0$.

Comment: @user400188: what about the case where your last inequality holds for infinity many $n$ **but not for all** $n$.